# How to set Heap size for Jmeter Slave instance

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

I have a distributed Jmeter Master-Slave set up. On increasing the throughput to a higher number, I started getting OOM exception for heap space.

[image: OOM Exception]

I found this post:
[How to Increase Heap size](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
to increase the HEAP size in the jmeter.bat file (windows in my case). However for Jmeter slave machines we don't launch jmeter via jmeter.bat but rather via jmeter.server.bat file. I checked this file doesn't have any HEAP memory parameter.

Any suggestions on how to increase the Heap memory size on Slave instances?

Comment: Thanks Ville for your edits. I will make sure in future I will ask questions with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [`jmeter-server.bat`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/bin/jmeter-server.bat) source code:

1. It respects [`JVM_ARGS`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/bin/jmeter-server.bat#L22) environment variable
2. It calls [`jmeter.bat`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/bin/jmeter-server.bat#L61) under the hood which in its turn respects [`HEAP`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/bin/jmeter.bat#L45) environment variable

So given you're on Windows you can do something like:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1G -Xmx10G -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M && jmeter-server.bat
```

and the JVM heap will be increased to 10 gigabytes for the slave instance.

---

Above instructions are applicable to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4), the behavior might differ on previous versions.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I am using 3.3 version, I will check out the corresponding code and give this a try. Got stuck in some other task and have not got chance to look into this.

Comment: This worked Dmitri thanks for your detailed explanation and more importantly teaching me to look up jmeter source code myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

The command to start the Jmeter slaves looks like:

```
nohup java -jar "/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1" -Dserver_port=10000 -s -j jmeter-server.log > /dev/null 2>&1
```

So if you want to change Java parameters just pass it after java:

```
nohup java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly ...
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. So basically I can pass in the arguments for this on each of the jmeter slave machines.